# Mono project System.dll conflict with Microsoft.Owin

Tags: mono

Microsoft.Owin seems to be loading the 2.0.0.0 version of System.dll along-side the 4.0.0.0 System.dll which is causing an issue in which a cast is failing because a System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal from System.dll is being cast to a System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal from System.dll 4.0.0.0

How can I force the mono project to only load the 4.0.0.0 System.dll?

This applies to Mono 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mono 3.8 beta release resolves this issue.  It must have been a defect in the type system for 3.6.